# Database design/ ERD diagram verification

Tags: database, relational-database, erd

I would be grateful if you could take a look to my ERD diagram which is related to description:

> Database contains persons records (since 1900). Each person can have
>   mother and/or father. Women can have one husband and men can have one
>   wife. Persons work in companies, which contain name and one chairman.
>   One person can work in one or more companies, employe on mandatory
>   contract or employment contract.

and the example query is:
find person (name and surname) which have largest numbers of grandchildrens.

and below is my ERD diagram but i'm not sure about the mother/father and wife/husband parts.
[image: Database model / ERD diagram]

Thanks in advance

Comment: I will point out that many many people especially in the early 1900s have multiple husbands and wives. They just don't have them at teh same time. Companies have multiple chairmen as well and company names are not unique.  Sometimes people even have more than two parents if they were later adopted.

Comment: Yes, i know there are many exceptions but i have to stick to the description. Thanks ;) I described all rules in description, there is no any business value in here. My database should only be comply with above description.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your "ERD", while commonly called such, is really a table diagram. A proper ER diagram has to be able to represent an ER model, meaning it should be able to represent ternary and higher relationships among other things. I recommend using Chen's notation for ER diagrams. That doesn't mean I'm against table diagrams - they're just used for different purposes. ER diagrams for conceptual models, table diagrams for physical models. In-between those are relational diagrams for logical models.

Your diagram also doesn't implement the given description very well. Consider "*Each person can have a mother and/or father*". Your `relationship` table allows a `person` to be associated with a number of `relationship_types`, but it doesn't associate two `persons` in parent and child roles. A better approach might be to have `father` and `mother` tables with `parent_id` and `child_id` fields that refer to `person_id`, or a single `parent` table with `parent_id, child_id, relationship_type` fields.

For married people, you could have a table with `husband_id, wife_id` fields. As with `father` and `mother` tables, this doesn't ensure that only persons of the matching gender is recorded in each role. It's possible to enforce this in both cases by creating disjoint subtype tables for genders of `person`. However, this isn't commonly done (and these days, flexibility in your data model is more likely to be seen as an advantage than a problem), and I suspect it may be overkill for your project.

Employment is better modeled. The main issue I see there is the one-to-one association between `agreement_type` and `employment_condition`. I assume `agreement_type` is meant to record `mandatory contract` and `employment contract`. However, with a one-to-one association, you can't have two or more employees with a `mandatory contract`. I believe each `agreement_type` should be usable in multiple `employment_conditions`.

I'm also concerned with the key(s) of `employment_condition`. `condition_id` and `agreement_name` are both indicated as foreign keys (orange) and part of the primary key (key icon). What does `condition_id` refer to, and why are they included in the PK? I would expect the combination of `person_id, company_id` to be enough to identify a many-to-many relationship between companies and employees.

Similarly, `person_id` in `company` is included in the PK. Based on the given description, I expected that `company_id` would determine both the `name` and the chairperson (`person_id`). BTW, I suggest you change the name of that field to `chairperson_id` to be more descriptive. Imagine if we had more persons in individual roles - we couldn't call each field `person_id`, right? It's generally more useful to name fields based on their role rather than their domain, though the two often coincide.